# How can I set the width of the last column of an html table to a percentage of the available width?

Tags: html, css, css-tables, spacing

I've got a table with two columns. I set the width of the first column by settings its header's width to 30%:

```
#TableFirstHeader
{
    width: 30%;
}
```

That works great, but if I try to set the width of the second header to 65%:

```
#TableSecondHeader
{
    width: 65%;
}
```

it is simply ignored. I can set that value to anything, and the second column always stretches to the end of the table.

All I really want is about a 5% gap between the second column and the right side of the table.

I've tried creating an empty column by setting a header of width 5% with nothing in it, but that doesn't do anything.

How can I get that column to use only 65% of the total width available (or like 90% of the width available to it, that would be fine, too)?

Comment: Have you set the width of the table to 95% and see if that helps?  By default the table wants to be the width of the container it is in.

Comment: Yeah, the thing is I want the rows to be the full width. It sounds silly, but I'm matching specifications.

Comment: I guess I'm not really following what it is you're trying to do.  Anyway you can screenshot what you have and mark it up to show how it should look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can´t, all columns of a table combined make up the width of the table.

I don´t know what you are trying to achieve exactly, but perhaps you can add a right padding on the cells of the last column to get the effect you want or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

```
<style type="text/css">
    table#YourTableId { width:95%; }
    th#TableFirstHeader { width:31.6%; }
    th#TableSecondHeader { width:68.4%; }
</style>
```

The second th does not necessarily need to be assigned a width. Also you could use

```
    table#YourTableId td:first-child { width:31.6%; }
```

instead. Matter of taste.

**Edited from here:**

Since you have clarified in the above comment, that - for whatever reason - the rows need to be 100% the table's container's width, I second jeroen's solution if the last column may have extra padding.

If you must have the second column at 65% the table's width (and not 70% with 5% right padding):

```
<style type="text/css">
    th#TableFirstHeader { width:30%; }
    th#TableSecondHeader { width:65%; }
    th#TableThirdHeader { width:5%; }
    div#Stretch { width:100%; }
</style>

<table>
    <tr>
    <th id="TableFirstHeader">Some Content</th>
    <th id="TableSecondHeader">Some Content</th>
    <th id="TableThirdHeader"><div id="Stretch"></div></th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

An empty third column would collapse. The empty div with 100% width of it's container prevents that behavior.